# Why can't a quiver be drawn over a surface?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, surface, matplotlib-3d

I am trying to draw 3 arrows over a surface using [quiver](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.quiver.html). The arrows seem to always be draw behind the surface. This is the result:

[image]

And this is the code to generate this result:

```
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def fun(x, y):
    return x ** 2 - y ** 2


if __name__ == '__main__':
    fig = plt.figure(dpi=160)
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
    x = y = np.arange(-3.0, 3.0, 0.05)
    X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
    zs = np.array(fun(np.ravel(X), np.ravel(Y)))
    Z = zs.reshape(X.shape)

    ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, cmap=plt.get_cmap('Blues'))

    ax.quiver([0], [0], [1], [0, -1, 0], [-1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 2.5], lw=4, color=['r', 'g', 'b'])  # The z is 1 unit above the surface

    ax.set_xlim3d(-3.5, 3.5)
    ax.set_ylim3d(-3.5, 3.5)
    ax.set_zlim3d(-8.5, 8.5)

    plt.show()
```

How do I draw these arrows over a surface? I am using matplotlib `3.1.1`, which is the latest version at the time of this question.

Comment: See https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/14508

Answer (score 0):

A hacky you solution you can use, while not ideal, is reduce the alpha of the surface.

```
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, cmap=plt.get_cmap('Blues'), alpha=0.5)
```

[image: example]

Comment: Thanks, but this solution will make the plot hard to see (regardless of the cmap used) when I print it out on paper.

Comment: I think there's something odd going on with the clipping of those arrows, without the alpha some of the arrows are complete obscured.  I don't think changing the zorder helps either.